# nav2-smac-planner package not available on foxy

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm trying to install the nav2-smac-planner package on Foxy but apt install can't find it. Is it not available?

Here seem to indicate it's available on Foxy both source and debian.
https://github.com/ros-planning/navigation2

Thank you in advance

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/414864/nav2-smac-planner-package-not-available-on-foxy/) by [guidout](https://answers.ros.org/users/145435/guidout/) on ROS Answers with karma: 25 on 2023-04-29

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Nartmangnourt](https://answers.ros.org/users/143866/nartmangnourt/) on 2023-04-29**:
nav2_smac_planner is available for humble but not for foxy i believe.
Foxy have a smac_planner package without (SmacPlannerHybrid, SmacPlannerLattice).

**Comment by [guidout](https://answers.ros.org/users/145435/guidout/) on 2023-04-29**:
that's what I thought but in the github page of navigation2 in the build status table it looks like it should be available for foxy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I answered this for you on the github page. Please don't cross post

https://github.com/ros-planning/navigation2/issues/3549

---

Originally posted by [stevemacenski](https://answers.ros.org/users/25940/stevemacenski/) with karma: 8272 on 2023-04-29

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1